# Cakephp app inconsistent behavior

Tags: cakephp

I have a cake php app, with a function that uploads and processes a file. 
The app and file upload works well if I connect to the live site from my development machine (it works the same as it does on my local development server). However, if I try the upload feather from other computers, nothing happens after I click upload/submit button. The page just refreshes and nothing else happens. I can't figure out the error because there are no errors.

Can anyone help with this? 
Not that all other features work, except file uploads.

The same behavior is seen on all browsers.

Comment: You'll need to do a little more debugging on this. Start by logging data about all received requests (`$_POST`, `$this->data`, Cookies, Auth status, whathaveyou) and see if you can spot any differences.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into a couple of things:

- Is the app somehow bound to your dev IP address? Try changing it and see what happens (make a note of the current one first).
- It has a bit of a smell of **ACL** access denial about it, or perhaps **Auth**?